# using php/mysql with google maps- is not diplaying markers

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I checked all similar subjects in passed week, but the issue still can't be solved. Could someone please help why my map is not display markers?

As [Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3#outputxml), I followed step by step:

1. Creating the Table
2. Populating the Table
3. Outputting XML with PHP ( Using PHP's DOM functions to Output XML (PHP5))
4. Creating the Map

About Item 3. (Outputting XML with PHP), I got:

A. phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php (Copy from google map api)

```
<?php
$username="root";
$password="***********";
$database="maps";
?>
```

B. phpsqlajax_genxml3.php (Copy from google map api)

```
<?php
require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
return $xmlStr; 
} 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect (localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
  echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
  echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
  echo '/>';
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

About Item 4 (Creating the Map), I got:

C. phpsqlajax_map_v3.html  (Copy from google map api)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Maps AJAX + mySQL/PHP Example</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {

        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'

      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;


      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml3.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
       var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>
  </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="load()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

To run the html file, there's only map without markers. Please help and thank you in advance.

Comment: what's the output of the phpsqlajax_genxml3.php?

Comment: The output is:         
<?xml version="1.0"?>      <markers>      <marker type="restaurant" lng="-122.340141" lat="47.608940" address="1521 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" name="Pan Africa Market"/>           <marker type="bar" lng="-122.344391" lat="47.613590" address="2222 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" name="Buddha Thai & Bar"/>        ...     </markers>

Comment: Dear Dr.Molle, I also put the output [here](http://www.snipsave.com/user/profile/unalin#9500) for your reference.

Comment: How can there be a & in the name(should be `Thai &amp; Bar`)

Comment: The markers are still not displayed after remove "&". [Here](http://www.snipsave.com/user/profile/unalin#9511) is the update output of phpsqlajax_genxml3.php. By the way, the previous database (including "Buddha Thai & Bar") was also downloaded directly from tutorial of [Google map api](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3)..

Comment: I've tested your code, there is no issue when the php-file returns the given XML, the markers will be drawn.

Comment: Thanks a lot for yr time. Maybe there're some environment problems or I should enable some functions first. Just not sure what's that.. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Can you provide a demo which exposes the issue?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you'd like me to do. Do you need the map w/o markers or other information?

Comment: Sorry to reply late. I tested the code on localhost originally. Now remove to the web. The map in localhost looks like : http://ufp.3eeweb.com/phpsqlajax_map_v3.html

Comment: sorry, but my antivir reports malicious software for this URL

Comment: Dear Dr.Molle, I tried several way to demo the map but failed. Not sure if the [capture photo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxyFfGzfZU88TEFTc0hleEhVNEU/view?usp=sharing) is helpful or not?